# Building a Control Panel Applet for Windows 8

Tags: winapi, panel

I have developed a control panel applet (.cpl file) that we distribute with our application, and it has worked fine on all previous versions of Windows but not on Windows 8.  The applet does not show up in the control panel at all.

Previously all we had to do was drop the .cpl file into the system32 directory and Windows magically found it and included it in the control panel.  But not Windows 8.  The applet exports the function CplApplet, which is how Windows is supposed to interface with it.

I'm wondering if there is an entirely new way to build control panel applets for Win8.  I've googled for "how to" articles but haven't come up with anything.  Perhaps someone has built a custom control panel applet and been able to deploy it on Windows 8.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For those that are interested I found this article helpful: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127450%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  I installed a dummy EXE as described and it appears in the control panel and comes up when I click on it.  Now I'd like to know how to make our UI fully integrated with the Windows control panel application.