# What language are the Windows Control Panel Applets (.CPL) files written in, and if they're compiled, what are they compiled in?

Tags: windows

So I've recently been looking into the Control Panel, to try to see how I might be able to create a custom applet for it, like sometimes you get a custom one when you use a printer, and I just can't seem to figure out how to make one. I've tried opening one of them in a code editing software, and assume that they are compiled as all I get is a bunch of random characters, but I'm not quite sure whether it is or not. I've looked for anything related to it, but the closest thing to an answer I have is [something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20429407/building-a-control-panel-applet-for-windows-8) about trying to make the applet show up, but it doesn't say how it's made, so its not really useful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/cc144185(v=vs.85)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two types of control panel applets:

- [.Exe files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/hh127450(v=vs.85)). These are normal applications and can be written in any language.
- [.Cpl files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/using-cplapplet?redirectedfrom=MSDN). These are actually normal .DLL files and can be written in anything that can produce a PE DLL with a named exported function (C/C++, Delphi or if you must, [C#](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports)).

Support for .Exe applets started in Vista and is now the preferred method according to Microsoft.

Comment: Ok so its basically just a .DLL file that can be exported yes?